# Import JSON records into database on Django and performing CRUD on JSON file

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

1) I have a JSON file (structure as seen below) and it has hundreds of records. How can I put these data into my Django model so that I am able to perform CRUD operations on the data?

I do not want to change the structure of the JSON file to match the output given by Django's model files as it can be tedious.

2) Please advise as I am also unsure where to put my JSON files in the project as well.

```
[
{
    "name": "A",
    "abbreviation": "a",
    "count": 1
},
{
    "name": "B",
    "abbreviation": "b",
    "count": 3
},
{
    "name": "C",
    "abbreviation": "c",
    "count": 55
}
    .
    .
    .
]
```

I am new and using Django 2.2 and I just finished "TheNewBoston" Django tutorial. I am using Django's model to makemigration and migrate to my database. I think I am using SQLite which is the default for Django.

Below is my code for my model.

```
class userDetail(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

EDIT: 
I created a data migration apart from the 0001_initial.py.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

def load_data(apps, schema_editor):
    data1 = [{
        "id": "A",
        "abbreviation": "a",
        "count": 1
    }]

    for data in data1:
        c = userDetail(id=data['id'],abbreviation=data['abbreviation'], count=data['count'])
        c.save()

dependencies = [
    'userDetail', '0001_initial.py',
]

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(load_data),
]
```

Comment: Create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) where you load the JSON into a python list, loop through each of the objects and save them one by one into the database.

Comment: I created a data migration apart from the 0001_initial.py named 0002_migrate.py but when i checked the localhost/admin page, the dummy records are not shown on the page. I added the codes in 0002_migrate.py in the edited version of this post above.

Comment: Your migration looks fine, did you run it? Note you should add a backward function as well to RunPython, so you can still undo, even if that function does nothing.

Comment: Yup, I did run it but when I checked my localhost:8000/admin, there were no such records in the database.

Comment: Oh it is working now. I just had to create my migration by using 'makemigrations --empty' and pasting my code in. I figured out it might be because I 'setInitial = true' as well. Thanks a whole lot!